# What is the best way to listen for changes in JTable cell values and update database accordingly?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, tablemodel

I'm building and app with multiple `JTables` and I need to detect when cell value change occurs so I can update it in the database. I tried `TableModelListener` and overriding `tableChanged`, but it fires **only when I click away** (click on another row) after I have edited a cell.

Any other way to do this?

Comment: I think that is possible to add Listener, everything depends of your XxxCellEditor, but safer way could be waiting after cell is validated on StopCellEdit (the same with MsExcell, without VBA/VBE), otherwise you have in risk

Comment: @mKorbel what kind of listener? I already tried TableModelListener.

Comment: not to add proper listener to the JComponent that representing Editor,

Comment: If possible, I'd try and wait till `setValueAt` on the table model is called, personally

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can implement the [`CellEditorListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/CellEditorListener.html) interface, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11113648/230513). Note that [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) itself is a `CellEditorListener`.

It may also be convenient to terminate the edit when focus is lost, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9226137/230513):

```
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", true);
```

More Swing client properties may be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SwingsClientPropertiesSummaryTable.htm).

Comment: +1 ooo... I like.  Too bad these properties are annoying/difficult to find documentation on.

Comment: Do you think it's a good idea to use `TableModelListener and `tableChanged()`?

Comment: Out of context, _good_ is hard to measure. Try to cover all normal exit paths and use a UPS.

Comment: @trashgod And how about `JTextArea`/`JTextPane`? Is there an event listener similar to this, where I don't have to use `DocumentListener` and update the database every time a character is entered? An event that fires on "`JTextArea` end edit" if what I'm after.

Comment: You could stash a working copy of the content in `java.util.Preferences`, as a hedge, and clear it on database commit. `VK_Enter` is bound to `insert-break`, so you'd need another gesture.

Answer (score 5):

I'm agreeing with @mKorbel - unless all your input is checkboxes and dropdowns, you're going to want to wait until the cell editing is stopped (you don't want to commit to the database every time a letter is typed in a textbox).

If the problem is that it's not committing after focus has gone to another component, add a `FocusListener` that stops editing the table when focus is lost on the table:

Example:

```
final JTable table = new JTable();
table.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        TableCellEditor tce = table.getCellEditor();
        if(tce != null)
            tce.stopCellEditing();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I'll try it out. But, what if the program is closed before focus is lost?

Comment: Unless it's a natural closing (not killed by the task manager or someone using System.exit in the code), I'm 90% sure the focus lost adapter will fire.  If not there's also the `WindowListener` that listens for the window closing.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't fire. But, I stop Cell Edit on app exit :) for all tables. I used @trashgod's simpler code to stop the editng when focus is lost and I now I just can't decide if I should save all changes on exit, or use the table model listener. I'm sure both will work now, but, which answer do I choose? I used trahsgod's code to sop cell editing and your idea to stick with not commiting everytime a letter is typed in.

Comment: Strange - It's seems I need to be more than 90% sure about things.  Good to know!

Comment: @Igor: For reference, `java.util.Preferences` makes a (platform-specific) best effort to record the last value `put()`.

Answer (score 0):

I use the enter key so everytime a user hit enter the cell will update.

```
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    JTable table = new JTable(dtm);

    table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {

                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                int column = table.getSelectedColumn();

                // resul is the new value to insert in the DB
                String resul = table.getValueAt(row, column).toString();
                // id is the primary key of my DB
                String id = table.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();

                // update is my method to update. Update needs the id for
                // the where clausule. resul is the value that will receive
                // the cell and you need column to tell what to update.
                update(id, resul, column);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: map KyeBindings not KeyListener

Answer (score 0):

This is also handy if you want to stop the editing on an event handler from selection change or save button.

```
if (table.isEditing())
    table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```